# Calculate on which side of a cuboid is a given point located?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, cubics

*Correct me if I'm using incorrect terms, I'm not well-versed with geometrical terminology*

I'm writing a code in which
I have a point &
I want to identify if the points lies on front, back, top, bottom, left or right side of a cuboid.

For Example,
in the 1st image, the point lies on 'top' side of the cuboid.
[image: example]

in the 2nd image, it lies on the bottom side
[image]
Does anyone have an idea how could this be solved?

Additional Info :
The cuboid is represented with co-ordinates in a 3D space.

Comment: What about points lying in two or three or those directions? And how is the cuboid represented?

Comment: Henrik, The cuboid is represented with co-ordinates in a 3D space. I didn't get your question about the directions

Comment: @KuldeepJ This is very easy, you have six equations of the six faces of the cuboid.  Let these equations be of the form $$n_i \cdot r = a_i $$ where $n_i$ is the normal **unit** vector to the $i$-th face, and is chosen to be pointing **out** of the cuboid, and $r = [x,y,z]^T$.  Then given a point $P$, compute the six **signed** distances from the face and that is given by $$ d_i = n_i \cdot P - a_i $$.  Now for the $i$-th face with a **positive** $d_i$, the point $P$ lies outside it.  It is possible to have more than one $d_i$ positive.

Comment: Imagine you're standing and have a cuboid (tightly) around your foot. A point on your shoulder is (might be, it depends on several things many of a physiological nature) (directly) above that cuboid, now imagine holding your arm stretched out in front of you, a point on your fingertip is above (but not directly) that cuboid but also in front of it. That was what I was goind at with my question about directions. Do you want multiple directions (like @HosamHajeer's multiple positive $d$'s) or do you just want to know that point is "above" (and when does it go from one direction to the other)?

Comment: Henrik, Hosam
as  Henrik mentioned, when the point is at my fingertip, I want the side to be front.
Though you are correct that it is also above the cube's bottom side, but my requirement is, when it is at fingertip the side should be front. 
when the point is at the other hand's fingertip, it could be back side. when the point on head will be top side

Comment: Then you need some clear definitions of when you want each result.

Comment: let's take the example that you suggested,
If a cuboid is around my foot, then a point below my foot will be on "bottom" of cuboid, similarly for point on chest, side will be "left", point on back will be "right" side, point on head will be "top", point on right hand's fingertip will be "front", point on left hand's fingertip will be "back"

Comment: I said *clear* definitions, that does not mean examples. Imagine a point moving along a stick you're holding in both hands, when does that point go from being "front" to being "top"?

Comment: If the point is moving upwards only, ideally the side should be "front". It is actually a valid concern at which moment the point shifts from "front" to "top". I'll need to articulate this.